# Yii2 Visibility Property on HTML

Tags: html, css, visibility, yii2

I have used

```
<li class="active" style="visibility:" . <?php User::isSuperAdmin() ?> . "">
```

But it is not working.

I know it's wrong, so what's the right thing to do?
I want that that specific `<li>` is only visible to a SuperAdmin user (condition is inside `User::isSuperAdmin()` function).

I am using AdminLTE asset bundle for my UI so I got rid of the `Nav` widget to achieve a collapsible side bar.

Somebody please help me with this.

Comment: You can add a class called `.hidden {display: none}` in CSS and add the class if `User::isSuperAdmin()`

Comment: where do I add `User::isSuperAdmin()`?

Comment: In the view you can echo the class name if a condition is met

Comment: Or you can put the `<li>` in a if block so that it renders if the condition is met

Comment: sorry, but can you show a sample code?

Comment: how do I set or use `User::isSuperAdmin()` in my `if` condition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71654/discussion-between-kaynewilder-and-anpsmn).

Comment: I am not familiar with Yii. What I meant was what @TimothéePlanchais has mentioned `<?= User::isSuperAdmin() ? 'hidden' : '' ?>`. It seems from your comment `User::isSuperAdmin()` itself is not returning the value. Make sure the value is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new WebUser class in the folder /components :

```
namespace app\components;

class WebUser extends yii\web\User
{
  public function isSuperAdmin()
  {
    //Define here how the superAdmin is defined
    return !$this->isGuest && $this->getIdentity()->username == 'superAdmin';
  }
}
```

In the configuration file (/config/web.php) :

```
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'app\components\WebUser',//The default class id edited
        ...
    ],
  ...
]
```

And after in your view :

```
<li class="active <?= Yii::$app->user->isSuperAdmin() ? '' : 'hidden' ?>">
```

---

For the menu, I recommand you to use the widget yii\widgets\Menu :

```
echo Menu::widget([
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
        ['label' => '...', 'url' => ['/site/superadmin'], 'visible' => Yii::$app->user->isSuperAdmin()],//Here is a good way
    ],
]);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-menu.html

Comment: hi. I am using the basic template and also, I already have the `public function isSuperAdmin()` in my `User` model: `public static function isSuperAdmin(){
        return !Yii::$app->user->isGuest && Yii::$app->user->identity->user_type == self::USER_TYPE_SUPER_ADMIN;
    }`

Comment: So in your view :
`<li class="active <?= User::isSuperAdmin() ? 'hidden' : '' ?>">`

Comment: it is not working. `<li>` Dashboard is still there. :(

Comment: I inspected element and the `<li>` is just `<li class="">` please help.

Comment: Maybe you forget the `echo` or the tag `<?=` ?.
And make sure that your function `isSuperAdmin()` returns correctly `true` (user `var_dump(User::isSuperAdmin())`)

Comment: I put `<li class="<?php User::isSuperAdmin() ? 'hidden' : '' ?>">` just almost like what you typed above.

Comment: NO, I wrote the tag `<?=`  which is different to `<?php` ! In your case you forget the `echo`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71656/discussion-between-kaynewilder-and-timothee-planchais).